# Compare two meta key values against each other inside the get_posts array?

Tags: php, post-meta, array

I'm banging my head to the wall all day trying to figure this out.

I have two meta keys a1 and a2 with numbers inside.

I'm trying to show posts that are a2 > a1.

In a nutshell, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
    
    
        'meta_query' => array(
//return both meta keys       
            array(
                'key'            => 'a1',
            ),
            array(
                'key'            => 'a2',
            ),
//only show posts that a2 meta_value is greater than a1  meta_value
            'a2' > 'a1'
        ),
        
    ));
```

I know it should be possible to do this somehow.

I'm not the only one in the world trying to compare whether one post's meta_key value is greater than other...

Desperately need help or any kind of solution.

Comment: note that this query if it were possible would be very slow and expensive, and that by using `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`, `suppress_filters` is enabled, so the query cannot be accessed by caching plugins, ensuring the result can never be cached for performance.

Comment: Have you considered storing the result of `a2 > a1` as meta, or a taxonomy? Then you would only need to query that. It would be faster and save you needing to filter the results with PHP.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. My only question is how and where should I use `update_post_ meta` to update the results right before querying my array? So that it won't lag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in the meta query I'm afraid.

You'd need to get *all* the relevant records in meta query, then make that comparison inside PHP, to filter out the records you don't need.

Comment: thanks, I have already done that actually, just thought I will have a clean array code that will handle all of this in one place. I guess I will have to stick to PHP comparison. Thanks.