# How to show 1 random post result without using an array?

Tags: php

Ok so basically I have this kind of situation.

My first step is to filter out the posts using an array, let's say using this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 99999999,


    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'status',
                'value'   => 'active',
            ),
        ),

    'orderby'               => 'rand'
));
```

So, let' say after the above code I'm left with a 20 random posts.

On the second step I use the PHP filter (which is not possible in the above array):

```
<?php 
$postid = get_the_ID(); 
$a1=get_post_meta( $postid, 'a1' , true );
$a2=get_post_meta( $postid, 'a2' , true );
if ($a1 < $a2): ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>  

<?php endif; ?>
```

The above filter's out the results, and after that I'm now left with, let's say, 5 post results.

My question is, is there a php code that will choose just 1 random post from that list?

I don't need 5, I just need 1.

Hope I'm clear.

Desperately need help here.

Comment: Ordering by `rand` can be extremely expensive and rapidly slows down as the size of your site increases. It's much easier to ask for the first post that occurs after a random date. Otherwise the database has to copy the entire posts table into memory, but with the order randomised.

Comment: Also if you only want a single post, why is the query asking for `99999999` posts per page? Meta queries don't scale either, your `status` custom field would make much more sense as a taxonomy with a significant boost in performance.

Comment: I have set `99999999` so that all of the posts would go through and none would left unshown. Because later I use the PHP to weed out those further. Thanks for the random date and `status` tips, I will check that out. Appreciate it. So there's no such code to left with 1 random post at the end?

Comment: That's not how the query works, that's just how many posts you want the database to return to php, not how many posts it should run the query on. Literally just set `posts_per_page` to `1`. The query always runs on all posts. Anytime you need to filter posts by wether they have something, store that as a taxonomy. Post meta is great for finding information about a post when you already know which post you want, or when you're doing numerical stuff that requires maths. But if you can put it in a bucket, group, filter, use a taxonomy.

Comment: I can't. If I set `posts_per_page` to `1`, then just 1 post will go to the PHP filter. And if that 1 post is NOT $a1 < $a2, then it won't go through. I need at least 1 post to go through, and to do that I need to feed as much posts into PHP filter as I can.

Comment: Anyway. you gave me an idea. I should get rid of the php filter somehow. I already have an idea of other logic I could use for this. That way I would be able to set `posts_per_page` to `1`.

Comment: I see, eitherway at some point you'll get more results back then PHP is able to process, and you'll either get a time limit error, or a memory limit error. This is not the solution you were hoping for.

Comment: I know you want to query for all posts were A1 < A2, but no, do not do that, it is a terrible idea, and unnecessary. Why not just calculate it when the post is saved and store it as a flag called `a1-is-smaller-than-a2`? What is A1/A2 anyway? You've asked about this before but never explained what it is or what the original problem/requirement was, and only asked how to implement solutions to the problem ( X Y Problem ), if you went back to the original issue feature you were trying to implement you'd get more useful answers

Comment: Hey Tom, A1 meta_value is constantly changing. Think of A1 as a 'spent' column. and A2 as a 'budget' set column, which is static. What I'm trying to do is to show posts that spent  < budget. If spent gets equal to budget, it won't show.

Comment: I don't see why that would change things. when A1 is updated, recalculate, there are hooks for when post meta is updated, this is a perfect use case for a taxonomy that's updated on post meta save/update. you'd even get an Admin view of all posts that are in/over/under budget based on the terms you use

Comment: Understood. I think that would solve the problem. Not a coder myself, just 5 months of learning time. Still lack with a simple logic. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks for the advice, Tom. I did exactly as you told me using on meta update hook. Working great now. One more question, you mentioned `to ask for the first post that occurs after a random date` instead of using `'orderby'               => 'rand'`. Can you elaborate more on this? Where can I find that? Does this goes to the array? I would appreciate any kind of resource.

Answer (score 0):

**Set `posts_per_page` to `1`.** Instead of asking for one page worth of results that contains `99999999` posts, ask for only 1 post per page instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code will help you to achieve 1 random post.**

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type'         => 'post',
'posts_per_page'    => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'value'   => 'active',
            'compare'   => '=', /* if equal to not works then you need to change 'IN'*/
        ),
    ),
'orderby'               => 'rand'
```

));

Comment: Thanks, yes I understand that. If you read my question and my comments, you will understand why I can't use this. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: @robert0 Ahh!! I think i understood. You mean that after 20 random post you want just 1 post object from that array? Right?

Comment: yes, I want for an array code to filter all of the possible 'active' posts,  (that's why I set to unlimited), and then use PHP to be left with 1 random post object.

Comment: @robert0
First of all you need to change into get_posts arguments. You want only active posts then  below is the actual code.


$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'status',
                'value'   => 'active',
                'compare'   => '=',
            ),
        ),
    'orderby'               => 'rand'
));

If above code still returns the all type of status posts then you should use array_slice function. array_slice($a,1,2);

Comment: @robert0 that's not what you asked. Hitesh answered the question you asked, not the problem you have. There was no mention of A1 < A2 as a requirement in the question. Hitesh's answer is correct.

Comment: @HiteshGandhi Robert doesn't want all posts where a meta is smaller than X, but rather to compare the meta of that specific post, which is not possible. This question is an attempt to work around that which failed asking how to fix it.

Comment: @TomJNowell No problem help him to solve his issue. Sometime happens user can't explain the question correctly.

Comment: @HiteshGandhi look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395667/compare-two-meta-key-values-against-each-other-inside-the-get-posts-array, OP tried to work around this by brute forcing their way to the solution, fetching all posts and then doing the comparison in PHP but realised that they had an array of all posts that matched their criteria, and only wanted one.